# How can I write an integration test for Marten (on top of PostgreSQL) that includes asynchronous projections in an asp.net context?

Tags: c#, postgresql, unit-testing, integration-testing, marten

I'm looking for a way to test functionality written using Marten. Not just as a unit test, but where integration with asp.net API's and actual saving to the database is tested. Moreover, I want to test whether async projections are generated as well. So to sum up, I would like to test whether the following is executed correctly:

1. Domain Driven Design styled command is received by a controller action
2. The command is translated into a domain event and that event has been saved to PostgreSQL
3. After a while a projection is asynchronously generated and saved to PostgreSQL as well

Marten does not provide concrete examples in their documentation. They do have [unit-test in their codebase](https://github.com/JasperFx/marten/tree/master/src/Marten.Testing), but these are not standalone enough to provide enough information to build your own integration tests in my opinion.

Given the following setup (inspired by [Marten examples](https://martendb.io/events/quickstart.html#event-store-quick-start)):

**Command**

```cs
public record StartQuest(
    Guid Id, 
    string Name, 
    int Day, 
    string Location, 
    params string[] Members) : IRequest;
```

**Aggregate, projection and events**

```cs
public class Quest
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class QuestPartyProjection : SingleStreamAggregation<QuestParty>
{
    public QuestParty Create(QuestStarted @event) => new() { Name = @event.Name };
    public void Apply(QuestParty view, MembersJoined @event) => view.Members.Fill(@event.Members);
}

public class QuestParty
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Members { get; set; } = new();
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public record MembersJoined(int Day, string Location, string[] Members);

public record QuestStarted(string Name);
```

**MediatR is used to delegate commands to command handlers**

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class QuestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public QuestController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpPost("[Action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Start([FromBody] StartQuest command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

```cs
internal sealed class StartHandler : IRequestHandler<StartQuest>
{
    private readonly IDocumentSession session;

    public StartHandler(IDocumentSession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(StartQuest command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var started = new QuestStarted(command.Name);
        var joined1 = new MembersJoined(command.Day, command.Location, command.Members);

        session.Events.StartStream(typeof(Quest), command.Id, started, joined1);
        await session.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        return Unit.Value;
    }
}
```

Which involves the following setup in my .net application:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMarten(x =>
{
    x.Connection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Marten")!);
    x.Projections.Add<QuestPartyProjection>(ProjectionLifecycle.Async);
})
    .OptimizeArtifactWorkflow(TypeLoadMode.Static)
    .AddAsyncDaemon(DaemonMode.HotCold)
    .UseLightweightSessions()
    .InitializeWith();;
builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(StartHandler));
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE 2023-12-10: I wrote documentation for Marten which gets updated and works better here: [Integration testing - Marten](https://martendb.io/testing/integration.html#integration-testing)

I created integration teest using [xunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit) (for declaring and executing tests), [TestContainers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Testcontainers) (for running a Docker PostgreSQL container o,n the fly), and [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing) for bootstrapping the application in memory for functional end-to-end tests.

My csproj has these package references (and a reference to the project to be tested):

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.2" />
<PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.5">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Testcontainers" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="7.0.0" />
```

First, since mvc.testing need a public entrypoint, I've added this to the program.cs

```cs
public partial class Program { } // Expose the Program class for use with WebApplicationFactory<T>
```

Now in the following code a custom WebApplicationFactory is created on top of Microsoft's end to end testing framework. A new docker instance for PostgreSQL is created for every run and the application configuration is overwritten by the connectionstring that points to that PostgreSQL instance.

```cs
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram> where TProgram : class
{
    public TestcontainerDatabase Testcontainers { get; } = 
        new TestcontainersBuilder<PostgreSqlTestcontainer>()
        .WithDatabase(new PostgreSqlTestcontainerConfiguration
        {
            Database = "db",
            Username = "postgres",
            Password = "postgres",
        })
        .Build();

    public override async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await Testcontainers.StopAsync();
        await base.DisposeAsync();
    }

    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        Testcontainers.StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        builder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(configBuilder =>
        {
            configBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(
                new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["ConnectionStrings:Marten"] = Testcontainers.ConnectionString
                }!);
        });
        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
}
```

I created an abstract integration class for reuse:

```cs
public abstract class IntegrationTest : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
    protected readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> Factory;
    protected IDocumentStore DocumentStore => Factory.Services.GetRequiredService<IDocumentStore>();

    protected IntegrationTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        Factory = factory;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 1. Start generation of projections
    /// 2. Wait for projections to be projected
    /// </summary>
    protected async Task GenerateProjectionsAsync()
    {
        using var daemon = await DocumentStore.BuildProjectionDaemonAsync();
        await daemon.StartAllShards();
        await daemon.WaitForNonStaleData(5.Seconds());
    }

    protected IDocumentSession OpenSession() => DocumentStore.LightweightSession();
}
```

And now my actual unit test is pretty straightforward:

1. Create a command to start the quest
2. Send it to my running asp.net application using a ready-to-use httpclient. JSON serialization is done by build in "System.Net.Http.Json"
3. Await asynchronous generation of projections
4. Fetch the projection from the PostgreSQL database and validate the content

```cs
public class QuestPartyTests : IntegrationTest
{
    public QuestPartyTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory) : base(factory)
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Start_ShouldResultIn_Party()
    {
        // Arrange
        var command = new StartQuest(
            Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name: "Destroy the One Ring",
            Day: 1,
            Location: "Hobbiton",
            Members: new []{ "Frodo", "Sam"});

        // Act
        await Factory.CreateClient().PostAsync("quest/start", JsonContent.Create(command));

        await GenerateProjectionsAsync();

        // Assert
        await using var session = OpenSession();
        var party = await session.Query<QuestParty>().SingleAsync();

        Assert.Equal(command.Name, party.Name);
        Assert.Equal(command.Members, party.Members);
    }
}
```